# How to manage a wired connection in network-manager using gnome-shell?

Tags: networking, network-manager, gnome-shell

I'm having trouble managing my ethernet connection (ASIX 88179 USB 3.0 adapter) in GNOME shell. I have a working WiFi connection listed in the control dropdown (with sound, brightness, user, system settings, shutdown and reboot, etc. function).

The device is neither recognized at boot, nor if I reconnect it by pulling the plug and replugging it. However, after setting `[ifupdown] managed=true` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and restarting `network-manager`'s `systemd` unit there's an "USB Ethernet unmanaged" in the control dropdown. Clicking `Connect` or `Wired settings` has no effect (meaning absolutely no feedback, not even a crash detected by apport). `journalctl -u network-manager` is empty. The device isn't listed in `nm-connection-editor` and adding a connection there has no effect on the GNOME shell control dropdown. The network section in the GNOME shell system settings section is empty except for proxy settings and VPN connections which I consider unrelated to the problem. `/etc/network/interfaces` only contains `source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d` and that directory is empty.

After a restart `[ifupdown] managed=true` remains, but the connection isn't visible in the control dropdown like it was after changing the value and restarting network-manager. A connection with `sudo dhclient enx00e07cc862a1` works fine, but has no effect on the UI.

I'm aware of different network connection management approaches through `/etc/network/interfaces` and `network-manager`. I know that `network-manager` can manage `interfaces` connections if `[ifupdown] managed=true` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`. I had no problem using both in Unity and my setup hasn't changed.

Comment: Did you download and install the Linux 4.x/3x/2.6.x Driver from http://www.asix.com.tw/products.php?op=pItemdetail&PItemID=131;71;112  ?

Comment: I would because it is a kernel driver for the device and it might give it better support.

Comment: @Terrance I installed 1.19.0 with `make && sudo make install && sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` and the output of `modinfo ax88179_178a` didn't change, so I assume I already installed them and forgot about it.

Comment: I think in the `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManger.conf` file, for the `ifupdown` it is supposed to be `[ifupdown]` then below that `managed=true`.  I just got home and my home system wasn't bringing up my eth0, but after I set that line of `managed=false` to `managed=true` then the eth0 has been coming up no problem.

Comment: @Terrance Sorry, the correct part of the config file is `[ifupdown] managed=true` with a newline after `[ifupdown]`.

Comment: I am grasping at straws here, but I did read somewhere while I was at home last night about the `/etc/network/interfaces` file and they said that the source-directory line should be `source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*` then they said that fixed it.